# Downloadable list of all majors across U.S. schools/colleges?

Tags: usa, education, database

I am looking for a downloadable list of all MAJORS across U.S. schools/colleges and across education levels (Highschool, Undergraduate, Graduate, Masters, Phd, Doctorate, Certificate/Short Term)

I have found a few sites where I can search for a particular major on the site's database, but I am looking for a downloadable list, preferably in spreadsheet format such as xls or csv.

Thanks!

Comment: US High Schools don't have majors. Either you graduate (and get a diploma) or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

For a really broad answer, you can use Wikidata via a [Sparql query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Facademic_major%20%3Facademic_majorLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP812%20%3Facademic_major.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100) on the property "[Academic Major](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P812)".

From my quick query, I think the data would need to be cleaned up a bit, and also made specific to US programs in your use.

[image]